# How to render a default view in Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I would like to render a default view/route when Vue.js loads.
At the moment, when the page loads, the header and the footer are shown and there is a small delay before the homepage is rendered. This causes the footer to touch the header.

Is there a way to render a default route on app load so that the footer doesn't "jump" to the end of the page as the view loads ?

App.vue

```
<main class="wrapper" id="app">
  <Header />
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <div :key="$route.path">
        <component :is="Component" />
      </div>
    </transition>
  </router-view>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [SSR](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html) techniques or [SSG](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#basic-tutorial).
Both changes how a [SPA](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/ways-of-using-vue.html#single-page-application-spa) behaves so mind if the effort worths the case.
Another approach is to use the splash screen from [PWA](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/) so you hid all your content while it's not ready.

Comment: Ok got the point, I wondered if there was another way but I guess I'll stick to SSR